# Exporting glsl from blender

Tags: blender, ogre

I created a mesh to which I have applied different materials with attached effects in GLSL: is there a way to export these programs?

I'm using blender 2.61

Comment: Which exporter are you using? Generally you must have a reference to the *.glsl* file on your *.material* (or *.program*) file. The shader file remains the same.

Answer (score 3):

There is a general GLSL exporter for blender which can be found [here](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?233186-Export-Materials-to-GLSL-Code). You'll still need to set up your Ogre material scripts to use those shaders though, and make sure you're rendering with the OpenGL render system. There is a little bit of reference for using GLSL shaders with Ogre materials [in the manual](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/manual/manual_21.html).